# Am I supposed to create a file use .env or os.py to store my secret key

Tags: python, django, heroku, environment-variables

I am ready to deploy my project. Everything I learned is on my own and I am confused about the SECRET_KEY placement. As stated above, am I supposed to create a file use, .env or os.py to store my SECRET_KEY? It's not to clear to me and none of my tutorials mention this.

EDIT I plan on hosting on heroku

Comment: It's up to you. I'd keep it out of version control, but beyond that there are many choices.

Comment: It depends a lot on how you're deploying it. Many hosting services have a special way of handling this.

Comment: I plan on hosting on heroku

Comment: This recent discussion in the Django developers group might give you some insight into current and future best practices: [Making Django more PaaS-friendly](https://groups.google.com/forum/?pli=1#!topic/django-developers/BAGhOKXGj4I).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are hosting on Heroku, you shouldn't manually create file on your server to store the SECRET_KEY, since it will be deleted on server restart. I would use Heroku environment variables, which can be set from your command line:

```
heroku config:set SECRET_KEY=some_very_secret_key
```

You can then easily read it in your Django settings:

```
os.environ['SECRET_KEY']
```

For more details see: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars

Comment: @ozren1963 so do I set up an if statement so that I can work locally?

Comment: I I tried that and got this message 'bash: !s****pgf: event not found'

Comment: @nothingness, please see this article about best practices regarding your project layout and organising your settings: http://www.revsys.com/blog/2014/nov/21/recommended-django-project-layout/. With this setup your can explicitly define your dev SECRET_KEY in settings/dev.py and keep it in version control, and in settings/prod.py read your production SECRET_KEY from env variable.

Comment: hello I have been researching and i think it's an escaping issue seemed to be caused by the bang

Comment: ye thats what it was, The example I saw didn't have quotation marks, so I did the same thing but I just added them and it saved the key just fine. but now my issue is it won't work locally